# This MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes Exception on ASP.net core

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core

I am working on asp.net core and mongo db. Here I am trying to implement transaction support using the below code

```
using (var session = await _mongoClient.StartSessionAsync())
{
    try
    {

        session.StartTransaction();
        await _dbCollection.InsertOneAsync(session,obj);
        //throw new Exception("No document found");
        await session.CommitTransactionAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //session.AbortTransaction();
        await session.AbortTransactionAsync();
    }
}
```

But it is throwing exception

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: This MongoDB deployment does not
>   support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your
>   connection string.

The below code, I am using to create connection

```
_mongoClient = new MongoClient(config.GetConnectionString("CarGalleryDb"));
        //MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = new MongoClientSettings();
        //mongoClientSettings.RetryWrites = false;

        _db = _mongoClient.GetDatabase(config.GetConnectionString("DBName"));
```

And my connection string is

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"CarGalleryDb": "mongodb://localhost:27017?retryWrites=false",
"DBName": "MongoTestDB"
```

},

Can anybody support me to resolve this one?

Comment: What is your connection string? Do you have `retryWrites=false` at the end of connection string?

Comment: "mongodb://localhost:27017?retryWrites=false" this one is my connection string

Comment: _mongoClient = new MongoClient(config.GetConnectionString("ConnectonString"));
            _db = _mongoClient.GetDatabase(config.GetConnectionString("DBName"));

Comment: How can you initialize your client? You can try to use `MongoClientSettings.RetryWrites` as well. I have added an answer please check

Comment: @SelimYıldız, Sorry for the late response. It is not working for me.I have updated the question with my connection creation code and connection string which I am using.

Comment: It seems you did not set `RetryWrites` correctly, It should be: `_mongoClient.Settings.RetryWrites = false;`

Comment: It is throwing another error "invalidoperationexception mongoclientsettings is frozen"

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `retryWrites=false` **at the end of the your** connection string.

See [Retryable Writes in Mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/)

> The official MongoDB 3.6 and 4.0-compatible drivers required including
>   the retryWrites=true option in the connection string to enable
>   retryable writes for that connection.
>
> The official MongoDB 4.2-compatible drivers enable Retryable Writes by
>   default. Applications upgrading to the 4.2-compatible drivers that
>   require retryable writes may omit the retryWrites=true option.
>   Applications upgrading to the 4.2-compatible drivers that require
>   disabling retryable writes must include retryWrites=false in the
>   connection string.

Or you can set in code by using `MongoClientSettings.RetryWrites`:

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_MongoClientSettings_RetryWrites.htm

Answer (score 0):

This error is produced when you are using the deprecated MMAPv1 storage engine. If you can you should upgrade to WiredTiger (and a newer MongoDB version since MMAPv1 is removed in 4.2 altogether).